# How to store Image Data in SQL VARCHAR(MAX) without a SQLCommand object

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, image

I've Googled the underlying question of how to store an image in the database and found many examples.  However, all of the answers I'm seeing (for example [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437937/Save-and-Retrieve-Image-from-a-SQL-Server-Database)), seem to use a SQLCommand as the solution whether they are using the older "image" type, text, or suggesting VARCHAR(MAX).  I am using SQL 2008 and SQL 2012

I'm having trouble incorporating this into my app since I have a legacy dll which will do some other work, and then store my image.  I want to wrap this into a SQL transaction.  The challenge is that the DLL is essentially a black-box to me since I cannot change the source code. The Dll exposes a parameter for an optional SQL statement it can run as part of its transaction.

The structure of the DLL is something like this:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Public Property ExtraSQL as string
    Public Function DoWork
      Dim sMainSQL as String
      'Start A transaction
      Execute(sMainSQL)
      If ExtraSQL <> "" Then
        Execute(ExtraSQL)
      End If
      If OK Then Commit Transaction
    End Function
End Class
```

My goal is to feed a SQL string into property ExtraSQL, but I'm not sure how to do this as all the examples are indicating something SqlCommand.Parameters(@Image).Value = byteArray().  I'm getting the image data from a web service.  Over its life cycle, it's formatted as an Image, a base64 Encoded string, a memorystream and a byte array, so converting between the types is not the problem.  I'm just unclear on the cleanest syntax for doing this.  Is it best to just take my original base64 string and do something like:

```
INSERT INTO tblImage (ImageData) Values ('Base64 blah blah')
```

and then whenever I read the image back out do this:

```
Public Function Base64ToImage(ByVal base64String As String) As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = Nothing

    Try
        'Convert Base64 string to byte array
        Dim btImage As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)
        Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(btImage, 0, btImage.Length)

        ms.Write(btImage, 0, btImage.Length)
        img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, True)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Return img
End Function
```

I would appreciate any supporting links, examples, and advice.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, considering you clearly can't send in parameterized SQL, yes that's the best approach. I sure don't like it because it's wide open to SQL injection. I would consider decompiling the assembly you're using and making it my own source code in the future.